# How would I find out the cost for flights that have already taken place?

Tags: tickets

I would like to know what the RT cost would have been to fly from CMI to MSP on July 30, 2021. Return on August 3, 2021.

Comment: Why do you think there's only one price?  Prices for the exact flight vary depending on when you book/how many seats are left, and there are several flights per day on that route.  I doubt you'll get a better estimate than just using the same as for a near-future date, as even those vary by a factor of 2.

Comment: This isn't well defined. Many different fares would have been available at different times. Are you expecting to find a distribution of all fares? An average price paid by actual passengers on that flight? A simulation of what would have been available to you at some point in time? Not that any of this would be easily available as far as I know.

Comment: Probably more than $200 and less than $2000.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is that there's no way to find out.

The price of flights varies not just based on the dates of the flights, but also multiple factors including :

- How far in advance of travel the tickets were booked
- How many seats were available at the time of booking
- The exact date the flights were booked, in terms of any fare sales/etc occurring at the time.
- The country that the tickets were booked in
- The exact route for the flight (there do not appear to be any direct flights between CMI and MSP)

and probably numerous other factors.

Even if you were to find someone that flew that exact route on those exact days, and asked them what they paid, it would not be a good indication as it still wouldn't cover most of the above points - in particular when the ticket was purchased.

You can get a very (very!) rough estimate for the price by looking at a similar flight sometime in the future. eg, October 22->27 (Friday -> Wednesday as per your original dates) shows prices ranging from $317 up to $547 for a 1-stop trip.  This MIGHT give an indication of a typical price for such a trip booked 3+ weeks in advance - or it might not as pricing can vary depending on the exact days (eg, school holidays, events occurring in the relevant towns increasing demand, etc, etc), sales occurring at the time of booking, etc.

Comment: Cost will also vary by the class of service: First Class costs more than Business which costs more than Coach...and there are additional levels offered by many carriers.

Comment: And the flexibility of the ticket.

Comment: ..and what was happening in the destination country around that time, for example sporting events..

Comment: You can slightly refine the estimate in the last paragraph by googling events around the original  dates at either end of the trip, and either choosing dates without events or ones with similar events as appropriate (big conventions, sporting events, concerts etc.)